# Testing login/logout with rspec (preserve session data between two API calls)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

I have the following API methods in my Rails app that I would like to test:

```
/current-user.json
/login.json
/logout.json
```

I want to run the following test in RSpec:

- Check that the user is logged out at /current-user.json
- Login by sending an access token to /login.json
- Check that the user is logged in at /current-user.json

The problem is that I set session[:user_id] in the control once the user logs in. It seems like the session doesn't carry over between requests. Is there a way to test in RSpec while preserving the session data between request?

Here is the code from my spec file

https://gist.github.com/2c077538bddfdb9c76bd

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the Mechanize library?

```
require 'Mechanize'
m = Mechanize.new
m.keep_alive = true
m.body = YOUR_JSON
m.basic_auth(YOUR_USER, YOUR_PASSWORD)
m.get("#{server_url}/login.json")
m.get("#{server_url}/current.user")
m.get("#{server_url}/login.json")
m.get("#{server_url}/current.user")
```